# How can i fill form data for client in other website?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, client, jsessionid

Maybe this is mission impossible...but here we go:

I have a website aaa.com where clients fill in some web forms, then my app will generate some data...the next step is to send that data(i.e. by POST) to bbb.com...after that i should send the client to bbb.com. In bbb.com the client will finalize his job(i.e. submit generated data).

About bbb.com: they are using jsessionid(cookie).

I'm using GAE(google app engine, python).

How can i do that? I need some hints!

Comment: Sounds like you want a web service from the one site?

Comment: Have you tried `urllib2` to send post request? http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html I'm not sure if that can be used in appengine.

Comment: the ugly solution is post data to bbb.com and retrieve a jsessionid then the client can use that jsessionid(i.e with cookie manager).